# ng if/else in a loop with multiple conditions

Tags: angular

I am trying to sort out how to accomplish this. I have a button group that gets generated in an ngFor loop:

```
<div class="btn-group float-right">
    <button *ngFor="let frequency of mapping?.frequency_mapping" [ngClass]="[profile?.frequency_name == frequency.label ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-outline-secondary']" type="button" value="{{ frequency.pk}}" class="btn">{{ frequency.label }}</button>
</div>
```

and where i add the text for the button, I would like to insert a class based on the value of this button's `frequency.label`

so something like this:

```
if frequency.label = condition A then class = classA
else if frequency.label = condition B then class = classB
else if frequency.label = condition C then class = classB
```

what would the best way to accomplish this?

basically i need the end result to be something like

```
<button><i class="fa fa-classA"></i>{{ frequency.label }}</button>
<button><i class="fa fa-classB"></i>{{ frequency.label }}</button>
<button><i class="fa fa-classC"></i>{{ frequency.label }}</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you’re just using the wrong format on ngClass. Get rid of the [ ] brackets.

Have a look [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

The case scenario you’re looking for is the 4th example on the “How to Use” section. You need it to evaluate an expression.

By using the brackets ngClass will be expecting an array of static strings for the styles, it will not evaluate the expression.